# How would I print this field in Django?

Tags: python, django, view, model

So I am trying to print out a field in my models.py file to a HTML file. (I couldn't think of any other word besides print). I am able to do it for the username, but I am struggling for the description/bio in this case.

I have tried things like self.user.bio, self.userprofileinfo.bio among other things

models.py relevant class

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True) 
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='default.png')
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

forms.py

```py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')


class UserProfileInfoForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','bio','image')
```

user_posts.html

```html
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="sidebar">
        <p class="active" href="#">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</p>
        <p>{{ view.kwargs.bio }}</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="content">
<div class="post">
        <h1 class='posttitle'>{{ post.title }}</h1>

                {% if post.published_date %}
                    <!-- <div class="postdate">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i> &nbsp; <p>Posted {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>   -->
                    <div class="posted-by">
                        <p>Posted by <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong>  {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="pub-post" href="{% url 'mainapp:post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
                {% endif %}

              <p class='postcontent' >{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried this code right here:

```py
return '%s %s' % (self.user.username, self.UserProfileInfo.bio)
```

However this did not work, and it didn't print anything off in the HTML. Thanks for any help :)

This is my views.py UserPostListView. I just realised I didn't have bio there. How would I be able to add multiple strings? Comma separated?

```py
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'mainapp/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-published_date')
```

Comment: post the code of your view.

Comment: done. i just need to know how to do multiple fields in there

Comment: you haven't posted your Post model but i think you can get your data by `{{ post.author.userprofileinfo.bio }}`.